# php-5.6 problem

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, php, dependencies

I installed a new server today, and after running successfully the ansible playbook, a couple of hours later I get this nice error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5.6 : Depends: php5.6-cli but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: php5.6-json but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: php5.6-opcache but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
```

The problem is that I don't find anywhere `libssl1.1` . The most recent is libssl1.0 .

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> ***UPDATE:*** The PPA maintainer has 'fixed' this, [according to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/639).  However, as an Ubuntu systems administrator and a linux sysadmin, I can't condone the approach made by Ondrej to this "fix" of providing `libssl1.1.0` which will break a lot of things in Ubuntu.  YMMV, but you use the PPA and their newer `libssl` at your own (*extremely-OS-breaking*) risk.

---

You have one of two cases, from what I can gather:

1. The PPA in question is built against a newer version of OpenSSL, which is not available in Xenial.

   In this case, the maintainer of the PPA and repository must go back and change the build environments to rely on 16.04's OpenSSL libraries.

   You'll need to reach out to the PPA maintainers to get help with this one.  We can't reliably support issues with a specific PPA here.

2. The PPA in question being added is for a newer release than 16.04.

   In this case, you need to make sure the ansible playbook and the managed systems are actually getting the *correct* distribution information to be set on the repository being added, and then update and install the updated PHP packages.

---

In both of these cases, it should be made known that PHP 5.6 is extremely old and if I remember right past end of life.  This means it should be replaced where possible with PHP 7.0 due to the end-of-life, not-updated state that 5.6 is in.

I would strongly suggest using PHP 7.0 where possible, rather than rely on these third-party repositories for PHP 5.6.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to get in touch with the ppa maintainer .

Comment: PHP 7 seems to be broken as well. Have ran into it myself and also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947497/php-7-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-now-fails-due-to-libssl-dependency-that-cant-be-re)

Comment: @razvanz It's more than likely an issue in the PPA or repository used then.  YOu may wish to use the standard PHP from the Ubuntu repositories instead of the PPAs.

Comment: The PPA maintainer answered : https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/639